# Filter an collection of tuples

Tags: filter, tuples, julia, iterable

I'm playing with iterables and comprehension in Julia and tried to code simple problem: find all pairs of numbers less then 10 whose product is less then 10. This was my first try:

```
solution = filter((a,b)->a*b<10, product(1:10, 1:10))
collect(solution)
```

but I got error "wrong number of arguments". This is kind of expected because anonymous function inside filter expects two arguments but it gets one tuple.
I know I can do

```
solution = filter(p->p[1]*p[2]<10, product(1:10, 1:10))
```

but it doesn't look nice as the one above. Is there a way I can tell that (a,b) is argument of type tuple and use something similar to syntax in first example?

Comment: For this specific example, you can also adjust the body of the function: `a -> prod(a) < 10`, but the `@tup` example is pretty neat idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to do exactly as you'd like, but here are some alternatives you could consider for the anonymous function:

```
x->let (a,b)=x; a*b<10 end
x->((a,b)=x; a*b<10)
```

These can of course be made into macros if you like:

```
macro tup(ex)
    @assert ex.head == :(->)
    @assert ex.args[1].head == :tuple
    arg = gensym()
    quote
        $arg -> ( $(ex.args[1]) = $arg; $(ex.args[2]) )
    end
end
```

Then `@tup (a, b) -> a * b < 10` will do as you like.

[Metaprogramming](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/metaprogramming/) in Julia is pretty useful and common for situations where you are doing something over and over and would like specialized syntax for it. But I would avoid this kind of metaprogramming if this were a one-off thing, because adding new syntax means learning new syntax and makes code harder to read.